# Validation of a number

Tags: algorithm, bash

When using [Luhn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) we need find out if a number is greater than 10 in order to  decide whether we should add the digits to continue the validation process. Does anyone know how to put this in a script in a way that is not a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable is `n` you can test if the length of it `${#n}` is greater than 1 and if so sum the digits, otherwise just pass it through, for example:

```
$ n=14; test ${#n} -gt 1 && echo $((${n:0:1} + ${n:1:1})) || echo $n
5
$ n=8; test ${#n} -gt 1 && echo $((${n:0:1} + ${n:1:1})) || echo $n
8
```

Comment: But the thing is that you don't know which number it is... The algorithm says that if the double of a number exceeds 10, then the number you should use is the addition of its digits... But you can't know if it's 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 or 19. That's why I am asking if there's a script that whichever the number is, to add it until the sum of its digits is less than 10

Comment: What if the number is greater than 100?

Comment: @anishsane According to the algorithm the number will never be greater than 9*2

Comment: @mVChr what you are saying i guess is right and thanks for your answer... But the thing is that in the way that i'm using it is in the credit card verification with Luhn's algorithm, and the thing is that the sum of the digits cannot be less than 0 or greater than 20, so if any number exceeds the number 10, i realized its enough to substract 9 from it and the result will be the addition of the numbers and it will sure be less than 10... But once again thanks for the time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way:
Take modulo 9:

```
$ echo $(( inputnum % 9 ))
```

e.g.

```
$ inputnum=14; echo $(( inputnum % 9 ))
5

$ inputnum=8; echo $(( inputnum % 9 ))
8
```